# Transformer hum coming in audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, transformer, speakers

I made an audio amplifier with a 6283 IC.

When I power the amplifier with a 12V battery it works fine without any hum.

When I power the amplifier amp with a 12V powered transformer,  hum comes from speaker from the transformer.

- What should I do?
- How do I fix the hum from the amplifier?

Comment: Please post schematics of everything you made, and if you're really nice, a link to the datasheet as well. Your question will be more likely to be answered.

Comment: You likely need to add a big capacitor after your rectifier.  The hum IMO is probably "ripple".   https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html

Comment: Big meaning upwards of 1000uF, and keep increasing it until the hum is as low as you want.